# R: Plotting 3D Objects in R (iris data)

Tags: r, plotly, data-visualization, data-manipulation

I am using the R programming language. I am trying to follow this tutorial over here: http://www.semspirit.com/artificial-intelligence/machine-learning/regression/support-vector-regression/support-vector-regression-in-r/

For the famous Iris dataset, I am trying to plot the 3D decision surface for the random forest algorithm (using tsne dimensions):

```
  library(Rtsne)
    library(dplyr)
    library(ggplot2)
    library(plotly)
    library(caret)
    library(randomForest)
    
  #data
a = iris
a <- unique(a)

#create two species just to make things easier
s <- c("a","b")
species<- sample(s , 149, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3, 0.7))
a$species = species
a$species = as.factor(a$species)

#split data into train/test, and then random forest 

index = createDataPartition(a$species, p=0.7, list = FALSE)
train = a[index,]
test = a[-index,]

rf = randomForest(species ~ ., data=train, ntree=50, mtry=2)

#have the model predict the test set
pred = predict(rf, test, type = "prob")
labels = as.factor(ifelse(pred[,2]>0.5, "a", "b"))
confusionMatrix(labels, test$species)


#tsne algorithm
tsne_obj_3 <- Rtsne(test[,-5], perplexity=1, dims=3)
df_m2 <- as.data.frame(tsne_obj_3$Y)

df_m2$labels = test$species
```

From here, I am trying to plot the 3d decision surface (http://www.semspirit.com/artificial-intelligence/machine-learning/regression/support-vector-regression/support-vector-regression-in-r/) :

```
axis_1 = df_m2$V1
axis_2 = df_m2$V2
axis_3 = df_m2$V3

plot_ly(x=as.vector(axis_1),y=as.vector(axis_2),z=axis_3, type="scatter3d", mode="markers", name = "Obs", marker = list(size = 3)) %>%
add_trace(x=as.vector(axis_1),y=as.vector(axis_2),z=df_m2$labels, type = "mesh3d", name = "Preds")
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
2: In RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(N, "Set2") :
  minimal value for n is 3, returning requested palette with 3 different levels

3: 'mesh3d' objects don't have these attributes: 'mode', 'marker'
Valid attributes include:
'type', 'visible', 'legendgroup', 'name', 'uid', 'ids', 'customdata', 'meta', 'hoverlabel', 'stream', 'uirevision', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'text', 'hovertext', 'hovertemplate', 'delaunayaxis', 'alphahull', 'intensity', 'intensitymode', 'color', 'vertexcolor', 'facecolor', 'cauto', 'cmin', 'cmax', 'cmid', 'colorscale', 'autocolorscale', 'reversescale', 'showscale', 'colorbar', 'coloraxis', 'opacity', 'flatshading', 'contour', 'lightposition', 'lighting', 'hoverinfo', 'showlegend', 'xcalendar', 'ycalendar', 'zcalendar', 'scene', 'idssrc', 'customdatasrc', 'metasrc', 'xsrc', 'ysrc', 'zsrc', 'isrc', 'jsrc', 'ksrc', 'textsrc', 'hovertextsrc', 'hovertemplatesrc', 'intensitysrc', 'vertexcolorsrc', 'facecolorsrc', 'hoverinfosrc', 'key', 'set', 'frame', 'transforms', '_isNestedKey', '_isSimpleKey', '_isGraticule', '_bbox'
```

A 3D plot is produced, but the 3D plane is completely gone.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

I am trying to make so that when you move your mouse over each point, for that point it will display the value of a$Sepal.Length, a$Sepal.Width, a$Petal.Length, a$Petal.Width, a$Species

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you called `add_trace()`, `z` is not assigned correctly. The labels won't plot; you need to plot the probabilities you identified, `z=df_m2$pred`.

There are multiple ways to fix the issues with the mesh plot, but the easiest would be to use `add_mesh` instead of `add_trace`.

```
plot_ly(x=as.vector(axis_1),
        y=as.vector(axis_2), 
        z=axis_3, 
        type="scatter3d",
        mode="markers", 
        name = "Obs", 
        marker = list(size = 3)) %>% 
   add_mesh(x=as.vector(axis_1), 
            y=as.vector(axis_2), 
            z=df_m2$pred, 
            type = "mesh3d", 
            name = "Preds")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I spent hours trying to figure this out! It's perfect! Just two questions: how do you make the labels (petal width, petal length, etc) when you move your mouse over each point? And is it possible to make points with label "a" as blue and "b" as red? Thank you so much!

Comment: Can tou please take a look at this if you have time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65434105/r-formatting-plotly-hover-text  thanks